# Why this R CSV column selection fails?

Tags: r, csv, statistics

I can use CSV file which has one column but not one column of many column file

```
dataA = read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE,sep = ",")
summary(dataA) # works!
```

Output: correct basic statistical analysis of values (min,1st Qu, ...). 
Now, multicolumn data where I want to use only the second column, so I do the following

```
ID,Age,Gender
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Code where `dataA[-(1), 2]` says remove header and take the second column

```
dataA = read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE,sep = ",")
dataA = dataA[-(1), 2]
summary(dataA) # does not work!:
```

Output: list of values in a list, no statistical analysis; it seems the output is like a string or something; here an example for bigger data set

```
male       5      27.78
     23  24  32  39  43  47  51  53  54  56  57  59  61  62  63  64  65  66  68 
  2   2   2   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   2 
 69  72  73  75  76  77  80  81  83  84  87  89 Age 
  3   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   1   0
```

Expected output like this

```
       V1       
 Min.   :23.00  
 1st Qu.:50.75  
 Median :65.00  
 Mean   :58.33  
 3rd Qu.:68.75  
 Max.   :81.00
```

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.1.1

Comment: When you read it in that way, everything looks like a string, right? Data types are at the level of the column, not the cell.

Comment: @Frank I added it in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multicolumn file has a header, so just do:

```
dataA = read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
dataA = dataA[, 2]
summary(dataA)
```